# Implementing the right conditions for a yum command for centos5 in Ansible

Tags: ansible, linux, centos

I'm currently working with a centos5 host and I have to install some packages with yum.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, centos5 doesn't support Ansible's yum module, since it requires python2 bindings, which are obsolete, so I have to use the `command` or `shell` modules and 'hard code' everything by myself.

My question is: what are the conditions I should implement to make a command/shell behave like Ansible's yum module and make it as much 'idempotent' as possible?

For the moment this is what I came up with:

#### When installing/updating a package

```yaml
- name: INSTALL (C5) - Install package
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: yum -y install <package>
  register: output_install
  changed_when: '"Installing:" in output_install["stdout"] or "Updating:" in output_install["stdout"]'
  failed_when: output_install["stdout"] is regex("No package.*available")
```

#### When removing a package

```yaml
- name: UNINSTALL (C5) - Remove package
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: yum -y remove <package>
  register: output_remove
  changed_when: '"Erasing" in output_remove["stdout"]
  failed_when: "No Packages marked for removal" in output_remove["stdout"]'
```

Do you have any suggestion or have already dealt with this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: > centos5 doesn't support Ansible's yum module

can you provide some evidence for this statement? A link, an error, something?

Comment: @BruceBecker you can see on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429110/centos-5-ansible-python-interpreter-usr-bin-python26-still-cannot-use-yum-mo), someone else already reported this issue

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this a bit with a centos5 container, but it's just too old and unsupported. The logic looks correct in your failed_ and changed_when though. I would answer the question yourself, with the "proof" showing the actual yum output